# Excel/VBA: Can't open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Function getProductStatus(adr As Range) As String

Dim networkLocation As String, networkPath As String, fileReference As String, srcSheetRef As String, c_formula As String
Dim sheet_src As Worksheet, sheet As Worksheet, wb_src As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim sheetName_src As String, sheetName As String

networkLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Path
networkPath = networkLocation & "\Locations\"

sheetName_src = "Sheet1"
sheetName = "Sheet1"

Set wb_src = ThisWorkbook
Set sheet_src = wb_src.Sheets(sheetName_src)

fileReference = networkPath & region_eval & "\ProductList.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileReference, ReadOnly:=True
Set wb = Workbooks("ProductList.xlsx")
Set sheet = wb.Sheets(sheetName)

c_formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sheet.Range("$K$2:$K$5000"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sheet_src.Range("A" & adr.Row), sheet.Range("$A$2:$A$5000"), 0))

getProductStatus = c_formula
wb.Close

End Function
```

The following formula works if entered directly in a cell:

```
=INDEX('\\..somePath\Locations\[ProductList.xlsx]Sheet1'!$K$2:$K$5000;MATCH('Sheet1'!A2;'\\..somePath\Locations\[ProductList.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$5000;0))
```

EDIT:

The question was previously about a #NAME error, but that has been resolved.. only to evolve into a worse one.

This function did, at some point, work as intended (after the #NAME was resolved). Between then and now, nothing has changed except closing the file being asked for. And now, opening the file before running the function does nothing.

How can I debug this? Why did Excel stop opening the file?

EDIT #2: The files opened in different instances, apparently, because the function does work if both files are open in the same instance. So the true question is now, why doesn't my code succeed in opening the file "on it's own"?

Comment: I would start by outputing c_formula to a messagebox or with debug.print to check if there is any problem with that formula. Are you running this function through a loop?

Comment: I don't know what the deal was, but after saving and re-opening the file, the #NAME error was gone. For a moment, the function worked as intended... but after opening and closing one of the files it is referencing, the function now terminates unexpectedly and without any errors on the line where the target workbook is being set.

Comment: I would guess it is because you have set the the vba function to go by workbooks names. So it is expecting them to be open. Change your code to include the fill pathname not just the workbook name

Comment: The two lines immediately preceding it sets the file path and opens the file, though... or is supposed to do that, anyway. Or is that not good enough either?

Comment: Ah didnt see the open some how. As long as it is open it should not need the full filename path. The #NAME does imply that someone is wrong with the formula. Do you loop the function and change the value of adr?

Comment: No loops, no changing of adr - it fetches adr from the call anyway (like this: =getProductStatus(K2) ). And the #NAME error is gone (or maybe "invisible" as of now due to the function terminating at the workbook object).

Comment: It is odd that it is not giving any error. Have you tried restarted Excel and trying again?

Comment: You may want to try the following:  
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fileReference, ReadOnly:=True)

Comment: I have restarted, and I have tried the suggestion from @Tom. Nothing changes. I have tracked the problem, though - Excel doesn't actually open the file anymore (which is odd, since it *did* open the file before!) - and I guess I should make a new question for it.